# Segmentation fault:secondary sort in SET C++11

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

I am trying to have a secondary sort based on the number of bits set in data structure named "set_type" which is nothing but a typedef for uint64_t. What could be going wrong? As, if I remove the statement return (n1 > n2) then the code executes perfectly. However, I want to store the nodes in SET in ascending order of double value and in descending order of number of bits set in SET_TYPE.

```
struct setNode {
    std::pair<double,set_type> data;
};

unsigned int bitCount (set_type value) {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (value > 0) {           // until all bits are zero
        if ((value & 1) == 1)     // check lower bit
            count++;
        value >>= 1;              // shift bits, removing lower bit
    }
    return count;
}

struct CompClass {
    bool operator() (const setNode& lhs, const setNode& rhs) const
    {

        if (lhs.data.first == rhs.data.first) {
            int n1 = bitCount(lhs.data.second);
            int n2 = bitCount(rhs.data.second);
            return n1 > n2;**//Statement causing error**
        }
        return lhs.data<rhs.data;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not complete. You left the definition of set_type out of the question. In the future, please create minimal self contained programs when forming questions. Aside from everything else, creating the minimal program will often lead you to understand where the problem is.

Everything else in this answer is pure guesswork.

First, I'm going to bet that the comparison line isn't the one segfaulting. This is easy to check by compiling your program without optimizations and running it in a debugger. I'm guessing that the compiler optimizes out everything once you remove the comparison, which is why it doesn't crash when that line is removed.

Second, I'm betting the problem is inside the definition of set_type. You probably ignored the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). Many forget that a C++ class has a default copy constructor unless you explicitly disable it.

If none of those answer your question, just create a minimal compiling example and post a new question.